# Gulp not creating JS and CSS files using main-bower-files

Tags: gulp, main-bower-files, gulp-load-plugins

I am using Gulp to concatenate/minify all JS/CSS files from the bower folder (using main-bower-files) and src folder respectively. I am using gulp-load-plugins to load the following dependencies from package.json (all of which exist in node_modules):

```
"dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "main-bower-files": "^2.13.1"
}
```

Here is the gulpfile.js:

```
// Include Gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

var src = 'src/';
var dest = 'public/';

// Include plugins
var plugins = require("gulp-load-plugins")({
    pattern: ['gulp-*', 'gulp.*', 'main-bower-files'],
    replaceString: /\bgulp[\-.]/
});

//Concat + Minify JS
gulp.task('js', function() {

var jsFiles = ['/src/js/*'];

gulp.src(plugins.mainBowerFiles().concat(jsFiles))
    .pipe(plugins.filter('*.js'))
    .pipe(plugins.concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(plugins.uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));

});
//Concat + Minify CSS
gulp.task('css', function() {

var cssFiles = ['src/css/*'];

gulp.src(plugins.mainBowerFiles().concat(cssFiles))
    .pipe(plugins.filter('*.css'))
    .pipe(plugins.concat('main.min.css'))
    .pipe(plugins.uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'css'));

});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['js','css']);
```

Gulp is not providing any errors in the console but neither the JS nor CSS file is being created.

Comment: `console.log(plugins.mainBowerFiles())` see if it returns empty array?

Comment: `plugins.mainBowerFiles()` is returning the array of file paths as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately the issue narrowed down to gulp-filter not returning any files. For anyone who is attempting a similar setup, I ended up taking a slightly alternate path by using mainBowerFiles to filter the files which achieved the same end result:

```
// Include Gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Include plugins
var plugins = require("gulp-load-plugins")({
    pattern: ['gulp-*', 'gulp.*', 'main-bower-files'],
    replaceString: /\bgulp[\-.]/
});


var src = 'src/';
var dest = 'public/';


//Concat + Minify JS
gulp.task('test', function() {

console.log(plugins);

});


//Concat + Minify JS
gulp.task('js', function() {

var jsFiles = ['src/js/*'];

gulp.src(plugins.mainBowerFiles('**/*.js').concat(jsFiles))
    .pipe(plugins.concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(plugins.uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'js'));

});

gulp.task('css', function() {

    var cssFiles = ['src/css/*'];

    gulp.src(plugins.mainBowerFiles('**/*.css', {
        overrides: {
            bootstrap: {
                main: [
                    './dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
                ]
            }
        }
    }).concat(cssFiles))
    .pipe(plugins.concat('main.min.css'))
    .pipe(plugins.cleanCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'css'));

});


// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['js','css']);
```

Comment: Hey Chad, so how do you then filter the other files out?  I tried your approach and it worked for me, but it's a little bit scary 

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and turns out the 'gulp-filter' was not working because of this line:

```
.pipe(plugins.filter('*.js'))
```

It should be the following:

```
.pipe(plugins.filter('**/*.js'))
```

The same should happen with the CSS and it works fine.